# Different URL-selected views for one controller method in Play framework 2.3

Tags: java, json, model-view-controller, playframework-2.3

Play, I understand, seperates answers to a request in two layers: The controller method puts all the data together, the view actually creates the output.

I have a function "get customer list". The controller creates, say, a List. Now, what I want is to have two outputs of this controller's result:

1) I want the usual HTML output, so a controller which prints

```
...<table><tr><th>Name</th>...</tr>
<tr><td>Smith</td>...</tr>
...
</table>...
```

2) From the same List, I would also create a JSON (or CSV or XML) file containing the customer data as JSON information.

From how I understand Play, it should be possible to obtain this by putting another view renderer at the end of the controller. I would have two URLs, say

```
/customer/list.html
```

and

```
/customer/list.json
```

which return the two differently formatted results but which use the same controller (which btw. is implemented in Java).

Can this be done? How can this be done? Or is my approach not sensible?

Best regards,
Dirk

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit reluctant to answer here since I'm unsure about the Play Java stuff, but you could take two approaches:

- have a route specified for every format you support (differing on .json, .html etc)
- parameterise the suffix and response differently in the action depending on it's value.

Suppose you support both HTML and JSON output (with HTML the default.) You could define a single route like this:

```
GET  /customer/list$format<(\.(:?html|json))?>   controllers.Application.renderMyList(format: String)
```

(Note: the .type suffix is optional, you could have `/list.html` or `/list.json` or just `/list`. Read up about regex dynamic route parameters [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaRouting).)

Your action might look like this:

```
public static Result renderMyList(String format) {
    List<Something> myList = getMyList();
    if (format.equals(".json") {
        Ok(convertToJson(myList));
    } else {
        Ok(views.html.myList(myList));
    }        
}
```

On the other hand you could explicitly define two routes pointing to the same action, with different **fixed** parameters:

```
GET  /customer/list.html  controllers.Application.renderMyList(format: String = ".html")
GET  /customer/list.json  controllers.Application.renderMyList(format: String = ".json")
```

But I think the first option is more succinct and generally nicer.

NB: I think for this kind of content-dependent stuff it's generally better to use [content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) instead of different URLs. You can read up on that [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaContentNegotiation).

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this does not solve the problem I really have. I want that framework to cope with the different formats without me writing any explicit code for this. Your "if (format.equals(...)" is precisely what I not want to have. :-) Anyway, I've leared in the meantime that Play is not suited for such an architecture. I'm still investigating how to cope with the situation.